# Why does this asyncio python code run sequentially?

Tags: python, python-3.x, boto3, python-asyncio

I am trying to speed up some AWS S3 calls (blocking IOs), with boto3/asyncio on python 3.9.
I thought I nailed it, but all coros still run sequentially. This is the shortest code I have, which shows what I understood and what goes wrong:

```py
import asyncio, boto3

class wtf:
    def __init__(self):
        self.s3 = boto3.client("s3")
        print(asyncio.run(self.get_all([f"key{n}" for n in range(10)])))

    async def get_all(self, keys: list[str]) -> list[int]:
        print("Start get_all")
        res = await asyncio.gather(*[self.get_stuff(key) for key in keys])
        print("End get_all")
        return res

    async def get_stuff(self, key) -> int:
        print(f"  Start get_stuff {key}")
        res = await self._nb_of_objects(key)
        print(f"  End get_stuff {key}")
        return res

    async def _nb_of_objects(self, key) -> int:
        print(f"    Start nb obj {key}")
        s3_objects = self.s3.list_objects_v2(Bucket="BUCKET_NAME", Prefix=key)
        l = len(s3_objects.get("Contents", []))
        print(f"    End nb obj {key}")
        return l

if __name__ == "__main__":
    wtf()
```

The output (for 2 keys, any number of keys will still be sequential) is:

```
Start get_all
  Start get_stuff key0
    Start nb obj key0
    End nb obj key0
  End get_stuff key0
  Start get_stuff key1
    Start nb obj key1
    End nb obj key1
  End get_stuff key1
End get_all
```

I have seen as workaround [aiboto3](https://pypi.org/project/aioboto3/) which I might end up using, but shouldn't my code work? There are some [tutorials](https://medium.com/tysonworks/concurrency-with-boto3-41cfa300aab4) around which seem to show that what I am trying to achieve is possible without aiboto3, but now I start to doubt them.

Comment: It is possible to run blocking code in a thread, see https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#executing-code-in-thread-or-process-pools

Comment: If boto3 calls are blocking just await for blocking calls won't change anything.
You can use a non-blocking lib as you mentioned it.
You can also use a ThreadPoolExecutor,
You can try something like `s3_objects = await loop.run_in_executor(self.s3.list_objects_v2(Bucket="BUCKET_NAME", Prefix=key))`.
To get the loop : `loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()`

Comment: Your specific issue is that `_nb_of_objects` doesn't await anything, so none of the other `self.get_stuff` coroutines have a chance to run until the one before it completes. You want to use something like `await asyncio.to_thread(self.s3.list_objects_v2, ...)`.

Comment: I think that @0x0fba and @dirn suggest the same thing, written differently. This does not work directly (I get `TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable` on the line of `await asyncio.to_thread` following @dirn suggestion). This points me in a better direction already, so thanks! If I'm forgetting something obvious, I'd love to hear about it, otherwise I'll carry on looking.